# SQL Server - How do i get multiple rows of data into a returned variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba

First question here so hoping that someone can help!

Im doing a lot of conversions of Access backends on to SQL server, keeping the front end in Access.

I have come across something that i need a little help with.

In Access, I have a query that is using a user-defined function in order to amalgamate some data from rows in a table into one variable. (By opening a recordset and enumerating through, adding to a variable each time.)

For example:

The query has a field that calls the function like this:

ProductNames: Product(ContractID)

And the VBA function "Product()" searches a table based on the ContractID. Cycles through each row it finds and concatenates the results of one field into one variable, ultimately returned to the query.

Obviously, moving this query to SQL server as a view means that that function will not be found as its in Access.

Can I use a function or stored procedure in order to do the same thing? (I have never used them before)

I must stress that I cannot create, alter or drop tables at run-time due to very strict production environment security.

If someone could give me an example id be really grateful.

So i need to be able to call it from the view as shown above.

Let say the table im looking at for the data is called tbl_Products and it has 2 columns:

| ContractID | Product |

How would that be done?! any help massively appreciated!

Andy

Comment: SQL Server isn't Access, a paradigm shift needs to happen here. There's no VBA function to run, your query needs to implement that lookup. Luckily, SQL Server is much better equipped than Access to do this. You can use CTEs, table-valued functions, or just nested queries, ...whatever rocks your boat. But nobody here can write that query for you. You need to look at what that VBA function is doing, and write an equivalent T-SQL query for it... then use it.

Comment: Apparently someone can... massive thanks to Albert D. Kallal for the great example and explanation. I knew i had to write a function using T-SQL i just needed a little help to get me off the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can most certainly do the same thing and adopt the same approach in SQL like you did in the past with VBA + SQL.

The easy solution would be to link to the view, and then build a local query that adds the additional column. However, often for reasons of performance and simply converting sql from Access to T-SQL, then I often “duplicate” those VBA functions as T-SQL functions.

The beauty of this approach is once you make this function, then this goes a “long” way towards easy converting some of your Access SQL to t-sql and views.

I had a GST calculation function in VBA that you would pass the amount, and a date (because the gst rate changes at a known date (in the past, or future).

So I used this function all over the place in my Access SQL.

When I had to convert to sql server, then I was able to use “views” and pass-though quires from Access and simply use “very” similar sql and include that sql function in the sql just like I did in Access.

You need to create what is called a SQL function. This function is often called a scaler function. This function works just like a function in VBA.

So in t-sql store procedure, or even as a expression in your SQL just like in Access!!!!

In your example, lets assume that you have some contract table, and you want to grab the “status” column (we assume text).

And there could be one, 1 or “several” or none!.

So we will concatenate each of the child records “status” code based on contract id.

You can thus fire up SSMS and in the database simply expand your database in the tree view. Now expand “programmability”. Now expand functions. You see “scaler-valued functions”. These functions are just like VBA functions. Once created, you can use the function in code (t-sql) or in views etc.

At this point, you can now write t-sql code in place of VBA code.

And really, you don’t have to “expand” the tree above – but it will allow you to “find” and “see” and “change” your functions you create. Once created then ANY sql, or code for that database can use the function as a expression just like you did in Access.

This code should do the trick:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ContractStatus]
 (@ContractID int)

RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare a cursor (recordset)
    DECLARE @tmpStatus varchar(25)
    DECLARE @MyResult varchar(255)
    set @MyResult = ''

    DECLARE rst CURSOR
       FOR select Status from tblContracts where ID = @ContractID
    OPEN rst
    FETCH NEXT FROM rst INTO @tmpStatus
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       IF @MyResult <> '' 
          SET @MyResult = @MyResult + ','
       SET @MyResult = @MyResult +  @tmpStatus
       FETCH NEXT FROM rst INTO @tmpStatus
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @MyResult

END
```

Now, in sql, you can go:

Select ProjectName, ID, dbo.ProjectStatus([ID]) as MyStatus from tblProjects.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! for this, it was so simple to understand. I was able to chop and change to pull out two fields from the query too so you description and coding is spot on! I can't thank you enough and hope to return the favour one day. This is going to make my life so much easier!